# Null pointer exception in selenium RC Using java

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception

I wrote two Methods
File name **Login.java**:

```
public int multiply(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
}

public void news(){
    selenium.open("http://10.0.0.33:8080/Olio/");           
}
```

I call these from a different class named **Bank.java**

```
public void testBank() throws Exception {
    Login lg = new Login(); 
    System.out.println(lg.multiply(4,8));
    lg.news();
    Thread.sleep(3000);             
}
```

The first method works, I get 32.
The second method throws a `java.lang.NullPointerExpression`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that `selenium` is `null`. Have you instantiated it anywhere ?

Comment: he has defined the selenium in bank.java. what is the process now...   I also needed the answer for same issue ...